# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly' but it work from workspace

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, ubuntu-20.04, modulenotfounderror

i have read all the posts related to this topic but i could not find the solution for my case.

In my ubuntu 20.04 I have installed plotly through the command:

```
pip3 install plotly
```

and if i launch python3 from command line and if i run:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

it works perfectly. But if i launch the same command from python script "test.py":

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi
import cgitb
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import calendar
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

it returns the error log:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

Anyone can help me? many thanks

Comment: Have you checked that you are using the same python installation in both cases? When you "say I launch python3", did you launch `/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: On the terminal try `which pip3` and `which python3` to see into which python you installed plotly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i resolved the issue by installing the module as a root user because in this way Python will try to search for the module’s name in the root directory and not in the usr one

thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

After a while looking for an answer that worked in my case and not found. I solved this problem by going to the directory where the Python version is installed and its package, for me:  (C:\Users\nslab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages). I deleted all files referring to 'plotly' and reinstalled this package (plotly) again with 'pip' from Terminal. Obs.: I use VSCode. So it worked